# Database and application design - removing constraints?

Tags: sql, architecture, windows-mobile, compact-framework, synchronization

I'm working on a Compact Framework app running on Windows Mobile. It's to be used by delivery drivers to tell them their next job and track spending etc. I have a SQL CE database on the mobile devices and SQL Server on the server. After struggling with major performance and configuration problems with the Sync Framework I ended up writing my own sync code using WCF. This works well and is a lot faster than the Sync Framework but I've been asked to speed it up further. Now we get into the details of the problem. Hopefully I can explain this clearly.

The synchronisation works one table at a time and is only one-way. Updates are sent from the server to the PDA only. Data travelling back to the server is handled a completely different way. First of all I delete any records on the PDA that have been removed from the server. Because of database constraints I have to delete from 'child' tables before deleting from 'parent' tables so I work up the heirachy from the bottom. E.G. I delete records from the invoice table before deleting from the products table.

Next I add new records to the PDA that have been added on the server. In this case I have to update the parent tables first and work down the heirachy and update child tables later.

The problem is that my boss doesn't like the fact that my app will keep a large table like the products table synchronised with the server when the delivery driver only needs the 
invoiceProduct table. The invoiceProduct table links the invoice and products table together and contains some information about the product. I mean that their database design is not normalised and the product name has been duplicated and stored in the invoiceProduct table as well as the product table. Of course we all know this is poor design but it seems they have done this to improve performance in this type of situations.

The obvious solution is to just remove the products table completely from the PDA database. However I can't do this because it is sometimes needed. Drivers have the ability to add a new product to an invoice on the fly. My boss suggests that they could just synchronise the large products table occasionally or when they try to add a product and find that it's not there.
 This won't work with the current design bacause if an invoice is downloaded containing a new product that is not on the PDA it will throw a database foreign key error.

Sorry about posting such a large message. Hopefully it makes sense. I don't want to remove my database constraints and mess up my nice data structure :(

Comment: Why the resistance to syncing the products table?

Comment: ...And, could you get away with only haveing (and syncing) part of the products table (just some of the columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to be running into some architecture problem. I work on a product that somewhat has a similar situation. I had a client-server application where the client loaded too much data that isn't needed.

We used ADO.NET (Dataset) to reflect what the database has on the client side. The Dataset class is like a in memory CE SQL Server.
Our company starts having bigger clients and our architecture isn't fast enough to handle all the data.

In the past, we did the following. These are no fast solution:

1. Remove the "most" of the constraints
   on the client side

   - all the frequently used data still have constraint in the
     dataset.
2. Create logic to load a subset of data, instead of loading everything to the client. For example, we only load 7 days of works data, instead of every work data (which is what we did in the past).
3. Denormalized certain data by adding new columns, so that we don't have to load extra data we don't need
4. Certain data is only loaded when it is needed based on the client modules.

As long as you keep your database constraint on the SQL Server, you should have no data integrity issue. However, on your PDA side, you will need to more testing to ensure your application runs properly.

This isn't an easy problem to solve when you already have an existing architecture. Hopefully these suggestions help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Dsum. There's lots of good ideas in there. I'm going to optimise all other parts of the sync code and only do some of this stuff if I have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

Add a created_on field for your products and keep track of when the last time each pda synced. When the invoice is downloaded, check if the product is newer than the last sync and if its re-sync the pda. Does not seem like it would screw up the DB too much?

Comment: Thanks Nate - not a bad suggestion. Would still require a bit of work. I'll keep it in mind.